# Why does my stored procedure not return the expected result?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

Hi i have the following stored procedure......

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `CouponCrusaderDev`.`sp_tblemailcampaignLoadTop4`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_tblemailcampaignLoadTop4`(p_UserID Int(11))
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
SELECT EC.*,(Select MailChimpCampaignID from tblcampaignschedule where EC.CampaignID=tblcampaignschedule.CampaignID AND tblcampaignschedule.MailChimpCampaignID IS NOT NULL) as MailChimpCampaignID,
(Select  count(MailChimpCampaignID) from tblcampaignschedule) as msent,CT.CampaignType, 
(Select tblcampaignschedule.ScheduleDateTime from tblcampaignschedule 
where EC.CampaignID=tblcampaignschedule.CampaignID  order By ScheduleDateTime desc limit 1) as CampaignDateTime,
(Select Count(*) from tblemailsent ES
inner join tblcampaignschedule CS on CS.CampaignSceduleID= ES.CampaignSceduleID
where ES.Status= 'ProcessedMessage' and CS.CampaignID = EC.CampaignID)as Sent
FROM tblemailcampaign EC
inner join tblcampalgntype  CT on CT.CampaignTypeID= EC.CampaignTypeID
inner join tblcompanies C On EC.CompanyID = C.CompanyID
WHERE (p_UserID = 0 OR C.AddUserID = p_UserID)
 order by CampaignDateTime desc limit 4
;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

And i have to show the MailChinpCampaignID that is not null so therefore i have do the following code........

```
SELECT EC.*,(Select MailChimpCampaignID from tblcampaignschedule where EC.CampaignID=tblcampaignschedule.CampaignID AND tblcampaignschedule.MailChimpCampaignID IS NOT NULL) as MailChimpCampaignID,
```

but it returns all the null mailchimpcampaignid's what can i do

Comment: Is this MySQL? Please simplify your question to remove information superfluous to your actual question. Show us what you expect your result to look like.

Comment: Suppose i have this line of code in mysql as:                   SELECT EC.*,(Select MailChimpCampaignID from tblcampaignschedule where EC.CampaignID=tblcampaignschedule.CampaignID as MailChimpCampaignID,     IN the above code i just need to get those MailChimpCampaignID who are not NULL so i have write it as: SELECT EC.*,(Select MailChimpCampaignID from tblcampaignschedule where EC.CampaignID=tblcampaignschedule.CampaignID AND (tblcampaignschedule.MailChimpCampaignID IS NOT NULL)) as MailChimpCampaignID, But its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is returning null because there is no row in 'tblcampaignschedule' with matching id and non-null `MailChimpCampaignID`. I think the best thing to do is inner join to 'tblcampaignschedule' and filter out the nulls that way..

This is how I would do it (made some other changes too to get rid of (I think) unnecessary sub-selects). However, unless you show us your table structure, with some example data, this is at best a guess.

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `CouponCrusaderDev`.`sp_tblemailcampaignLoadTop4`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_tblemailcampaignLoadTop4`(p_UserID Int(11))
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
SELECT EC.*,
Select tcs.MailChimpCampaignID as MailChimpCampaignID,
count(distinct tcs.MailChimpCampaignID)as msent,
CT.CampaignType, 
max(tcs.ScheduleDateTime) as CampaignDateTime,
Count(*) as Sent
FROM tblemailcampaign EC
inner join tblcampalgntype  CT on CT.CampaignTypeID= EC.CampaignTypeID
inner join tblcompanies C On EC.CompanyID = C.CompanyID
inner join tblcampaignschedule tcs ON EC.CampaignID=tcs.CampaignID AND MailChimpCampaignID IS NOT NULL
inner join tblemailsent ES ON tcs.CampaignSceduleID= ES.CampaignSceduleID AND ES.Status= 'ProcessedMessage'
WHERE (p_UserID = 0 OR C.AddUserID = p_UserID)
 order by CampaignDateTime desc limit 4
;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

EDIT:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `CouponCrusaderDev`.`sp_tblemailcampaignLoadTop4`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_tblemailcampaignLoadTop4`(p_UserID Int(11))
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
SELECT EC.*,
Select tcs.MailChimpCampaignID as MailChimpCampaignID,
(Select  count(MailChimpCampaignID) from tblcampaignschedule) as msent,CT.CampaignType, 
(Select tblcampaignschedule.ScheduleDateTime from tblcampaignschedule 
where EC.CampaignID=tblcampaignschedule.CampaignID  order By ScheduleDateTime desc limit 1) as CampaignDateTime,
(Select Count(*) from tblemailsent ES
inner join tblcampaignschedule CS on CS.CampaignSceduleID= ES.CampaignSceduleID
where ES.Status= 'ProcessedMessage' and CS.CampaignID = EC.CampaignID)as Sent
FROM tblemailcampaign EC
inner join tblcampalgntype  CT on CT.CampaignTypeID= EC.CampaignTypeID
inner join tblcompanies C On EC.CompanyID = C.CompanyID
inner join tblcampaignschedule tcs ON EC.CampaignID=tcs.CampaignID AND MailChimpCampaignID IS NOT NULL
WHERE (p_UserID = 0 OR C.AddUserID = p_UserID)
 order by CampaignDateTime desc limit 4
;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: At max(tcs.ScheduleDateTime) as CampaignDateTime, should i replace it with my code that is (Select tblcampaignschedule.ScheduleDateTime from tblcampaignschedule 
where EC.CampaignID=tblcampaignschedule.CampaignID  order By ScheduleDateTime desc limit 1) as CampaignDateTime,
If yes than how???

Comment: Whether it should be written as follows:(Select tblcampaignschedule.ScheduleDateTime from tblcampaignschedule 
where EC.CampaignID=tblcampaignschedule.CampaignID  max(tcs.ScheduleDateTime) )as CampaignDateTime,

Comment: It gives me errors:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Select tcs.MailChimpCampaignID as MailChimpCampaignID,
count(distinct tcs.MailCh' at line 5
(0 ms taken)

Comment: Would i just copy paste your code or make changes to it??? Like where you have write BEGIN SELECT EC.*, so i  would replace it with BEGIN
SELECT EC.*, (Select MailChimpCampaignID from tblcampaignschedule where EC.CampaignID=tblcampaignschedule.CampaignID) as MailChimpCampaignID,